# Different outcomes when adding a ".0" to the divisor

Tags: c++

Can someone explain why the outcome is different in my code?

I was trying out the easy problems in Codechum when I encountered something confusing, this was my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int num1, num2, num3;
double avg;

int main(){

    cout << "Enter three numbers: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    avg = (num1+num2+num3) / 3;

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "Average of the three numbers: " << avg; 

    return 0;
}
```

I was confused as to why I only got 3 out of the 6 test cases correct, I looked everywhere on my code and I still had no idea so I viewed the solution and noticed that there's a ".0" on the divisor of the solution code, so I tried it and it worked on all 6 test cases.  This was my code after

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int num1, num2, num3;
double avg;

int main(){

    cout << "Enter three numbers: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    avg = (num1+num2+num3) / 3.0;

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "Average of the three numbers: " << avg; 

    return 0;
}
```

*I might have missed something so small or overlooked a very simple idea...*

Comment: integer division against floating division.

Comment: This is not `C`. Your problem is integer division. When you do something like `3/2` you would expect to get `1.5` but with integer division you loose anything after the decimal point so you are left with `1`. When you use a `double` (your `3.0` is a double literal), this wont happen.

Comment: I removed the C tag since it's not a C question

Comment: storing the result into a double variable doesn't change the type of division. only its operand change the type of division.

Comment: To be brutally honest, if you don't know the difference between `3` and `3.0` in C++, then you have skipped quite a lot of the basics that you need to actually be able to program in C++. And you should definitely not try to use so-called "judge", "assessment" or "competition" sites as a learning resource, because they are *not*. Instead invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and take actual classes.

Comment: *I might have missed something so small or overlooked a very simple idea* -- This is covered in any C++ book, right at the first or second chapter.  `(num1 + num2 + num3) / 3` -- that is all integer division, giving you an integer result.  It doesn't matter what the variable type is on the left side of the `=` sign.

Comment: I don't know CodeChum that well, and can't find any reviews. But good sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
 For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: Before using CodeChum — at all — you should first learn C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression:

```
(num1+num2+num3) / 3
```

Both operands of the division operator have integer type, so integer division is performs which truncates any fractional part.  While is this expression:

```
(num1+num2+num3) / 3.0
```

The constant `3.0` has floating point type, and since this is one of the operands of the division operator, floating point division occurs which retains any fractional portion.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between this:

```
(num1+num2+num3) / 3;
```

and this:

```
(num1+num2+num3) / 3.0;
```

is that the latter expressions is (automatically) changed by the compiler to

```
((double)(num1+num2+num3)) / 3.0;
```

That is, in the first case the division is done in `int`s and truncated, and in the second case it's done in `double`s.